# Get result from HttpGet Request in "getter" method Angular 7 service

Tags: angular, angular7

This is probably pretty simple, but Angular isn't exactly my forte and it's taking me a bit more time than I anticipated. I have a service that calls an external API, and I want to get the variable on app initialisation and to use it in multiple other components.

I have the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from  '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatabaseConnectionService {

  API_URL: string = "http://localhost:4044";

  apiResult;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.dbConn.getApiRoot()
    .subscribe(
      data => this.apiResult = { message: data['message'] }
    );
  }

  getApiRoot() { 
    return this.http.get<Apiroot[]>(this.API_URL);
  }

  returnApiResult() {
    return this.apiResult;
  }

}
```

In any of the other components, I need to be able to call the `returnApiResult()` and get the value of the variable, but it returns as empty since it's an observable (which I think should have already be assigned, since it's in the constructor for the service). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Its not necessary that you will get the response data since you initiated the call in constructor.

Comment: Even though it's in the constructor, it's asynchronous, so there is no guarantee is has finished loading when you call `returnApiResult`. Instead, you should return the actual Observable, and call `subscribe` in the components that need it

Comment: @user184994 Yeah, it works that way, I was kind of hoping to initialise all the data on application load, and just access it through the components. This way it would minimise the API requests too.

Comment: What version of rxjs are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, change the code like so:

```
  import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

  //...

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.apiResult = this.dbConn.getApiRot().pipe(shareReplay());
  }
```

By using the [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator, it will share the results among multiple subscribers, and replay the results. This way, your components can still subscribe:

```
  this.service.apiResult.subscribe(() => console.log("Done"))
```

But the data will only need to be loaded by the service once, on application load

Comment: Perfect - it does the trick and leaves only 1 line of logic in the other components which is what I was going for. I think it's worth mentioning that last() is contained in "import { last } from 'rxjs/operators';", other than that this is the correct answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure this will only load the data once if more than one component subscribes to it.

Comment: @AviadP  Having just played around with this, you're completely right, my mistake. @Neekoy I have made a change to use `shareReplay` instead of `last`, which should be more efficient. Please use that instead